# How can I set the href="" of an anchor Tag to weblink from my model

Tags: razor, anchor, href, asp.net-core-mvc

In am passing a model to a MVC view, which has got one field that stores an absolute URL (for exmaple http://goolge.com)- I am trying to add this to a anchor tag but the system keeps adding the host and controller to the URL.

The code in the view looks like this:

```
<a  href="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Offers.Infolink)">@Localizer["InfoLink"]</a>
```

The respone however adds the host and controller name. Therefore, the link shows like this:

```
http://localhost:51114/de/Home/http://google.com
```

What I would like is just:

```
http://google.com
```

I have tried all kind of changes to the way I pass the string into the href="" but whatever I do, the result is the same.

Comment: Did you tried `<a  href="@Model.Offers.Infolink">@Localizer["InfoLink"]</a>` ?

Comment: Thanks regnauld. I have tried that and the same happens. I have also tried to assign the value to a local string variable and insert the variable instead but it does the same thing.

Comment: @item.Offers.Infolink should work without the display for. Are you sure the values are being saved correctly? Maybe they are being save as 'http://localhost:51114/de/Home/http://google.com'

Comment: lokuzt  - yes I have tried that too. Still the same issue. The data is saved correctly.